# Joining 1 more table to mysql join

Tags: mysql

I have a sql statement which is as follows below:

```
select c.*
from manga_chapter c join
     (select manga_source_id, max(manga_episode_number) as maxmen
      from manga_chapter
      group by manga_source_id
     ) cc 
     on c.manga_source_id = cc.manga_source_id and
        c.manga_episode_number = cc.maxmen;
```

I want to add another table which is

```
select manga_picture, manga_description from manga;
```

The connection is

a is manga_source table , b is manga table

```
where a.source_id = b.source_id
```

How do I draw manga_picture,manga_description together in the top sql statement above.

I tried

```
select c.*
from manga_chapter c join
     (select manga_source_id, max(manga_episode_number) as maxmen
      from manga_chapter
      group by manga_source_id
     ) cc join
     (select manga_name,manga_picture
      from manga) ccc 
     on c.manga_source_id = cc.manga_source_id and
        c.manga_episode_number = cc.maxmen and
        ccc.manga_id = c.manga_id;
```

The error I get is

```
Unknown column 'ccc.manga_id' in 'on clause'
```

Comment: `ccc.manga_id` must be selected in the subquery or do a direct join without a subquery. `select c.*
from manga_chapter c join(
 select manga_source_id, max(manga_episode_number) as maxmen
 from manga_chapter
 group by manga_source_id
)cc on c.manga_source_id = cc.manga_source_id 
and c.manga_episode_number = cc.maxmen 
join manga ccc 
ccc.manga_id = c.manga_id;`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty sorry but I tried your query seems to not get the result, it give me an error. ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ccc.manga_id = c.manga_id' at line 1

Comment: Sorry I missed `on`  `join manga ccc on ccc.manga_id = c.manga_id`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty are you able post the full query on the answer, because I think in the sql statement you type on comment did not select the manga table. Thanks! I would try and mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the other join directly instead of sub-query as below, if you need to select some data from `manga` table then just select them in the select part 
`select c.*,ccc.yourcol_name,...`

```
select c.*
from manga_chapter c join(
 select manga_source_id, max(manga_episode_number) as maxmen
 from manga_chapter
 group by manga_source_id
)cc on c.manga_source_id = cc.manga_source_id 
and c.manga_episode_number = cc.maxmen 
join manga ccc on
ccc.manga_id = c.manga_id;
```

**UPDATE**
After providing the table DDL , it could be seen that there is no direct relation between `manga` and `manga_chapter` they are rather related via the table `manga_source`

So you need to re-factor the query as

```
select c.*
from manga_chapter c join(
 select manga_source_id, max(manga_episode_number) as maxmen
 from manga_chapter
group by manga_source_id
)cc on c.manga_source_id = cc.manga_source_id 
and c.manga_episode_number = cc.maxmen 
join manga_source mc on mc.manga_source_id = cc.manga_source_id  
join manga ccc on
ccc.manga_id = mc.manga_id;
```

Comment: I got this error ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'join manga ccc on
ccc.manga_id = c.manga_id' at line 8

Comment: Ah I had typo fixed it.

Comment: Its okay now ! Thanks

Comment: The issue is there is no direct relation between `manga` and `manga_chapter` they are rather related via the table `manga_source` so you need that table in the join too.